# Where to get my log of my application deployed in Azure web apps

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service

Used Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory for by asp.net core web api logging and getting log in my local.
Now I deployed it azure web app but cannot find the log file in Kudu. Any hints?

Comment: You shouldn't write to a file when running an app on the cloud. Write logs to console and cloud provider collects the logs for you, which you can access through the dashboard

Comment: i guess another way would be to use [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger). It should override `ILogger` implementation through the DI so you might not have to change your code further

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to access your log files from the url like below?

https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/LogFiles/Log_13_April_2021.txt

"LogFiles" => Folder name where you have kept your files

"Log_13_April_2021.txt" => Name of your log file.